# SvelteKit with typescript no intellisense inside html?

Tags: html, typescript, jsx, svelte, sveltekit

I have simple page component, but my intellisense isnide html is not working... Also after renameing property it doesn't rename inside html, it just breaks...
Typescript version: 4.8.4
Here is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { Blog } from "$lib/store/BlogStore";

    let blog: Blog = {
        id: 0,
        activeFrom: new Date(),
        isPublished: false,
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        content: {
            rows: [],
            notesHolder: []
        },
        previewImageUrl: '',
        tags: [],
        header: '',
        user: '',
        isPremium: false
    };
</script>

<div>
    {#each blog.<no intellisense here? as row}
        <div>
            <h1>{row.id}</h1>
            <p>{row.type}</p>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

here is my Blog interface:

```
export interface Blog {
    id: number;
    activeFrom: Date;
    isPublished: boolean;
    updatedAt: Date;
    content: BlogContent;
    previewImageUrl: string;
    tags: string[]; //tag
    header: string;
    user: string; // user
    isPremium: boolean;
}
```

Comment: It works strange, after i type for example blog.content and wait few seconds i get content as suggestion, but renaming content still doesn't get renamed in HTML...

Comment: I am facing a similar issue where the intellisense for object properties fails inside the each block. Works for if block probably but definitely fails for each block. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me more an issue of your IDE / extensions, rather than svelte/sveltekit itself.

You didn't specify what is you IDE and what extensions you have installed. But, in vscode with the recommended extensions (svelt for vs code) is indeed that example not working for me, but it seems to be a bug, because if you try:

```
{#if blog.tags}
p
{/if}
```

The autocompletion works, so intellisense clearly does work in the html. I wasn't able to find this as a reported issue in the repo, but I think this question may better be a github issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20intellisense). So feel free to raise the issue there if you also think is a bug at that end.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I am using VSCode and I've installed Svelte for VS Code extension. Intellisense actually work most of the time, but I am more consirned about renaming property doesn't get renamed in html... so i would need to do it manually ? Is that something connected to svelte or extension again ?

Comment: Extensions, the extension you have belong to the svelte project itself, but svelte itself is just a compiler that has nothing to do on how do you write the code or rename it. In any case, if you are finding bugs in the behaviour of the extension, look for them in github and raise them, if they are not already there, or even contribute to solve them.  In any way you can rename in multiple files using ctrl+alt+f

Comment: @Wings did you reported these bugs?

Comment: Hey thanks again for answering. I will report soon.
Renaming in multiple files didn't help with this issue..